# How to access all the sub folders name and contained files of the same subfolders and make a XLSX or CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv, python-os

My problem is a little tricky. I hope I am able to explain my problem.
In a directory, there are 22 folders.

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
Folder 4
...
Folder 22
```

Each folder contains at least 12 images.

```
Folder 1/
  image1.jpg
  image2.jpg
  image3.jpg
....
  image12.jpg

Folder 2/
  image1.png
  image2.jpg
  image3.jpg
....
  image12.jpg

Folder 3/
  image1.jpg
  image2.png
  image3.jpg
....
  image12.jpg
```

At first, I want to take the image's name from a folder in a column and then the name of the folders where the images are in another column. Then in the third column want to take the extension on the images. And finally, want the last column which contains the level of a folder and then save in "`xlsx`" or in "`CSV`" format.

> I tried:

```
path1 = ('/content/drive/MyDrive/imagesFolders/')

subDirectory = list(os.walk(path1))
print(subDirectory)
sd = subDirectory[1][2]
sd
```

> Output:

```
[('/content/drive/MyDrive/imagesFolders/', ['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5', 'Folder6', 'Folder7', 'Folder8', 'Folder9', 'Folder10', 'Folder11', 'Folder12', 'Folder13', 'Folder14', 'Folder15', 'Folder16', 'Folder17', 'Folder18', 'Folder19', 'Folder20', 'Folder21', 'Folder22'], []), ('/content/drive/MyDrive/imagesFolders/Folder1', [], ['IMG20220610090323.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST000_COVER.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST001.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST002.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST009.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST010.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST011.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST012.jpg', 'IMG20220610090331.jpg', 'IMG20220610090325_BURST019.jpg', 'IMG20220610090335_BURST000_COVER.jpg', 'IMG20220610090335_BURST017.jpg']), .............. #continued for 22 folders.

['IMG20220610090323.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST000_COVER.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST001.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST002.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST009.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST010.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST011.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST012.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090331.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090325_BURST019.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090335_BURST000_COVER.jpg',
 'IMG20220610090335_BURST017.jpg']
```

> A demo format is shared below:

[Demo-File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WSGbQKfAy8wRfLHKz4QrWjSWh2Slhz2VZTje3qCx5AA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

All these things did in google collab!

In bellow I shared the solution:

```
import os
import xlsxwriter
```

> Path initializing where our excel file will save with the name

```
path1 = os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/excel')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data_path_reader.xlsx')
```

> By default worksheet names in the spreadsheet will be
> Sheet1, Sheet2, etc., but we can also specify a name.

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("First _Sheet")

> Use the worksheet object to write
> data via the write() method.

```
worksheet.write('A1', 'Image Name')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Folder Name')
worksheet.write('C1', 'Extension')
worksheet.write('D1', 'Label')
```

> Set the path of the main directory

```
path = os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/images')
current_directory = os.listdir(path)
subDirectory = list(os.walk(path))

sd = subDirectory[0][1]
lengthOFsd = len(sd)
lengthOFsd = lengthOFsd + 1
```

> Initializing the Column and Row value

```
row1 = 1
row2 = 1
row3 = 1
row4 = 1

col1 = 0
col2 = 0
col3 = 0
col4 = 0
```

> This loop is for 1st column images name, 3rd column for extensions
> name of files in subfolders, 2nd column folder name, and fourth column
> label.

```
for j in range(0,lengthOFsd):
  subd1 = list(subDirectory[j][2])
  foldername = os.path.basename(subDirectory[j][0])              # subFoldName = subDirectory[0][1][j]  # # This is the folder name without use os.path.basename
  label = j-1
  for imgname in subd1:
    extension = [imgname.split('.', 1)[1]]
    print(extension)
    worksheet.write(row1, col1, imgname)
    worksheet.write(row2, col2 + 1, foldername)
    worksheet.write_column(row3, col3 + 2, extension)
    worksheet.write(row4, col4 + 3, label)
    row1 += 1
    row2 += 1
    row3 += 1
    row4 += 1

workbook.close()
```